# C: How to copy over null terminator to structure member, in cleaner way?

Tags: c, string, null, strcpy

Essentially I am tokenizing a string and `strncpy`ing the string found to a structure member, i.e. stringid. It of course suffers from the problem of lack of termination, I have added an extra array space for it, I've no clue how to add it properly.

I had done it like so:

```
my_struct[iteration].stringID[ID_SIZE-1] = '\0' //updated
```

I am unsure if that really works, it looks horrible IMO.

Str(n)cpying a null character, or 0, results in a warning generated by GCC and MinGW:

```
warning: null argument where non-null required (arg 2)
```

Am I blind on how to do this in a clean manner? I was thinking of memsetting the member array to all zeros, and then copying the string in to nicely fit with null termination. Do you have any suggestions or practises?

Comment: What is the size of `stringID`?  If it's `ID_SIZE` then you're one past the end of the string with that assignment.

Comment: I corrected the example, I was really meaning ID_SIZE-1 to access the last array. It was purely an example of how "ugly" the solution looked. The -1 makes it even more so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, null terminating the way you suggested isn't horrible at all and I personally very much like it.

The best way, in my opinion, would be to define it as a macro in similar fashion:

```
// for char* blah;
#define TERMINATE_DYNAMIC_STRING(str, len) str[len] = '\0';
// for char mytext[] = "hello";
#define TERMINATE_STRING(str) str[sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]) - 1] = '\0';
```

Then you can use it all around your code as much as you want.

On Windows Microsoft gives you the following functions which null terminate when copying string: [StringCchCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I find this answer inspiring, as I had seen it as ugly only because it looked unnecessary compared to a strcpy if it would work. Writing a macro, wrapper, or what I have chosen (leave it be) is my solution.

Comment: Note that the value of `sizeof` is in units of `char`, so for strings you never need to involve `sizeof` of actual elements. For this approach, I'd rewrite `TERMINATE_STRING` as just str[sizeof str - 1] = '\0'.

Comment: sizeof() returns the size in bytes. The code I offered will work correctly for both WCHARs and CHARs

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. Beware that `strncpy()` has very unexpected semantics, it will always 0-fill the buffer if not totally filled by the string, and it will not terminate the string if it completely fills the buffer. Both of these are weird enough that I recommend against using it.
2. Never index an array with it's size, like `stringID[ID_SIZE]` seems to be doing; that is out of bounds.

The best solution is to write a custom version of `strncpy()` that is less weird, or (if you know the length of the input) just use `strcpy()`.

**UPDATE**: If the length of your input tokens is static, but they're not 0-terminated in the source buffer due to your tokenization process, then just use `memcpy()` and manual termination:

```
const char * token = ...; /* Extract from tokenization somehow. Not 0-terminated. */
const size_t token_length = ... /* Perhaps from tokenization step. */
memcpy(my_struct[iteration].stringID, token, token_length);
my_struct[iteration].stringID[token_length] = '\0';
```

I don't see a need to "wrap" the above in a macro.

Comment: The input length of each token is static, so it being too small and it terminating automatically is not part of my requirement, sorry for unclarity. A custom solution seems good (strlcpy I've heard of is a replacement often used)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, `strncpy` has odd semantics.  The idiomatic way to do a bounded string copy is to `strncat` onto an empty string:

```
my_struct[iteration].stringID[0] = '\0';
strncat(my_struct[iteration].stringID, src, ID_SIZE-1);
```

This always appends a terminating NUL, (and fills at most ID_SIZE characters including the NUL).

Answer (score 0):

I ended-up writing a strncpyz(char* pszTo, char* pszTo, size_t lSize) function that forces the NULL termination. This works pretty-well if you have a library to put it in. Using it also requires minimal code changes.

I'm not keen on the macro approach because somebody will pass a pointer to the wrong macro.